# C# WPF Show Image from Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, image

i'm a student and i am bad at programing. 
I saved the images in my mysql database for each player. I created a program where I can list some soccer players from my database. When i click on a listed player in datagrid, a new window appears with the information about the player. Everything works, but now i want a picture of the selected player to be displayed on the information window from the database. Can anybody help me? My english is not the best (i'm 17) so i hope you can understand what i mean.

This is what i tried to do but i don't know how to continue. PS. It's in WPF.

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Bilder FROM spieler WHERE Bilder='{8}'");
        MySqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            while (rdr1.Read())
            {
                // image1... I don't know what to write here
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fehler: " + ex);
        }

        rdr1.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get it using a `byte[]` casting beforehand:

```
while (rdr1.Read())
{
   byte[] data = (byte[])reader[0]; // 0 is okay if you only selecting one column
   //And use:
   using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
   {
      Image image = new Bitmap(ms);
   }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**
In WPF, use the `BitmapImage`:

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
{
    var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
    imageSource.BeginInit();
    imageSource.StreamSource = ms;
    imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    imageSource.EndInit();

    // Assign the Source property of your image
    yourImage.Source = imageSource;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this line: `Image image = new Bitmap(ms);`  i get an error, it says that 'Bitmap' could not be found. Any idea?

Comment: @user3718026 Yes, your object don't have a reference for the assembly which should hold the `Bitmap` class. Since you're using WPF, just add the appropiate image to your window. See my update.

Comment: One thing missing. You have to set `imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;` (before `EndInit`) in order to make the bitmap load before the stream is closed. It may work without that option on a MemoryStream, but only by accident. Setting this option is required when you want to close an image stream immediately.

Comment: @YairNevet I have one more question, I get an error at data in this line: `using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))` It says that data is not in the context. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is column's type where you hold the image?
You could try somehing like this

```
Image tmp = ImageConverter.ConvertFrom(rdr1.GetStream("photo"));
```

where photo is name of your column